# React JS got error of Error: Parse Error: Line 27: Unexpected token . at http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/ajax_call.html return {cell.data.row}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the content from database in a react js

React JS got error of

```
Error: Parse Error: Line 27: Unexpected token .     at http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/ajax_call.html  return {cell.data.row}
```

my code is:

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/machineTest.css">
<head>

<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "anand";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db_name",$username,$password);
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student");
$result->execute();
?>
<?php
 foreach($result as $row){

    echo "$row[0]$row[1]$row[2]$row[3]$row[4]";

}

?>
    </body>
</html>

and react code is :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Initial Data Via AJAX</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
      <body>
      <div id="example"></div>
          <script type="text/jsx">
              var ImageCollect = React.createClass({
                    getInitialState: function() {
                        return {
                          phpData: []
                        };
                    },

                    componentDidMount: function() {
                        var self = this;
                        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
                          var collection = result.data.children;
                          if (this.isMounted()) {
                            this.setState({
                              phpData: collection
                            });
                          }
                        }.bind(this));
                    },

                    render: function() {
                        BDdata = this.state.phpData || [];
                          return (
                            <div>
                              Images: 
                              {BDdata.map(function(cell){
                                  return {cell.data.row}// I think i want to change this line.
                              })}
                            </div>
                        );
                    }
              });

                React.render(
                <ImageCollect source="http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/index.php" />,
                  document.getElementById('example')
                );

          </script>

      </body>
</html>
```

I just want to display the content retrived from the index.php on react page

Comment: What is the `result.data.children` and what it does look like?

Comment: That is from previous code.May I remove this? or what should i replace this?

Answer (score 0):

In a JSX context, `{}` denotes a JavaScript expression. In a JavaScript context, `{}` either denotes a *block* or an *object literal*.

`return {cell.data.row}` is in a JavaScript context (the `.map` callback), and because of the position of the `{...}`, they are interpreted as object literal.

But `{cell.data.row}` is not a valid object literal and I doubt you want to create an object here anyway. Use

```
return cell.data.row;
```

instead.